# How to 'mute' using Voxeet?

Tags: audio, conferencing

I'm trying to get the [Voxeet](https://www.voxeet.com/) API up and running in the browser.

Their [basic example](https://www.voxeet.com/documentation/sdk/samples/basic-audio-conference) works well, but now I would like to add a [mute/unmute](https://www.voxeet.com/documentation/sdk/conferencing#muteunmute) button.

I do not understand where and how to use the unmute/mute code, such that the participant objects(?) are available to mute/unmute.

Comment: you can get current participant in `VoxeetSDK.session.participant`

Comment: Do you know if I can mute everyone else? Or I would have to send this directive outside of the SDK and then mute locally?

Comment: Yes, you can mute by passing the participant id. Add a listener `participantAdded` and store details of the participant and then pass these details of particular participant user has clicked on.

Comment: @MastaBaba - Did you get the mute/unmute to work?

Comment: @arnoldtm Actually, I have not tried, as I switched to Agora when getting frustrated with Voxeet. :/

Answer (score 1):

**Mute**

```
VoxeetSDK.conference.mute(VoxeetSDK.session.participant, VoxeetSDK.session.participant.isMuted);
let isMuted = VoxeetSDK.conference.toggleMute(VoxeetSDK.session.participant);
console.log(isMuted)
==> true
```

**Unmute**

```
VoxeetSDK.conference.mute(VoxeetSDK.session.participant, VoxeetSDK.session.participant);
let isMuted = VoxeetSDK.conference.toggleMute(VoxeetSDK.session.participant);
console.log(isMuted)
==> false
```

Comment: how do you know which pariticpant your refering to?

Answer (score 1):

with the Web SDK, to mute / unmute the local participant you can use the following code:

```js
# Mute the local participant
VoxeetSDK.conference.mute(VoxeetSDK.session.participant, true);

# Unmute the local participant
VoxeetSDK.conference.mute(VoxeetSDK.session.participant, true);

# VoxeetSDK.session.participant <= represents the local participant.
```

Documentation: https://dolby.io/developers/interactivity-apis/reference/client-sdk/reference-javascript/conferenceservice#mute

Comment: This blog post may be helpful and describes iOS and Android cases too: https://dolby.io/blog/how-to-mute-participants-in-a-conference